# Accessing intercept factor levels for a linear regression

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm doing a conjoint exercise. Part of that is running a linear regression on a bunch of factor level outputs. I'm trying to figure out a programmatic was to find the optimal choice. The regression output looks like such:

```
(Intercept)   3.8750     0.9960   3.890  0.00367 **
Screen10     -0.3750     0.6591  -0.569  0.58329   
CellY        -0.3750     0.6591  -0.569  0.58329   
Price300     -0.8333     0.8022  -1.039  0.32599   
Price500     -1.1667     0.8022  -1.454  0.17982   
Battery8      1.1667     0.8022   1.454  0.17982   
Battery12     1.8333     0.8022   2.285  0.04814 * 
OSiOS         1.6667     0.8022   2.078  0.06752 . 
OSWindows    -1.6667     0.8022  -2.078  0.06752 .
```

What's not shown is the factor levels Screen7, CellN, Price100, Battery4 and OSAndroid which are represented by the intercept.

My optimal choice is the factors that have the highest coefficients or part utilities, which from above would be Screen7 (0), Price100 (0), CellN(0), Battery12(1.833), OSiOS(1.6667).

I'm trying to write a for loop to iterate over each factor level battery, cell, screen, etc and find the max value of the coefficient and store that in a list giving me programmatically what I see  above.

so far I have:

```
for (n in colnames(design_DF)){
    for (i in 2:length(design_DF)){
        choice = rep(NA, length(design_DF)-1)
        coef = dummy.coef(lm1)[i]
        coef2 = coef$n
        choice[i] = max(coef2)
    }
}
```

grep will give me the index of the coefs, then store the coef values and 0 representing the coefficient for the missing factor level.

The problem is as you can see, I can't seem to figure out how to store the factor level value in a list when the max value is 0. The output of index and coef variables in the code are for say "price" are:

```
> index = grep("Price", names(lm1$coefficients))
> index
[1] 4 5
> coef = c(lm1$coefficients[index], 0)
> coef
  Price300   Price500            
-0.8333333 -1.1666667  0.0000000
```

but the max value of that list is 0 and I need to be able to store, price100 as the variable in the list.

Thanks

if it helps these were my "instructions"

*The `which.max()` function can be useful for determining the index associated with the largest value in a list of values.  For example, `index = which.max(part_worths)` would return the index to the largest value in `part_worths`.  If attribute level names are stored in a list of strings names `levels`, then `levels[index]` would return the name of the attribute level with the highest part-worth.*

I attempted the solution below but the supply gave me:

```
> sapply(choice[lengths(choice)>1], max)
  Screen     Cell    Price  Battery       OS 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.833333 1.666667
```

I can't seem to access the screen.7, cell.N, etc

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what is the original question and clarify that the incorporation of the dummy.coef part was taken from an answer and is not part of the original question. Also questions posted should have complete reproducible code and inputs.  See top of [tag:r] tag for information on asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the dummy coefficients.

```
library(nlme) # Alfalfa

fm <- lm(Yield ~ ., Alfalfa)
dc <- dummy.coef(fm); dc
## Full coefficients are 
##                                                                                    
## (Intercept):       2.033333                                                         
## Variety:            Cossack       Ladak      Ranger                                 
##                  0.00000000  0.09458333 -0.01916667                                 
## Date:                  None          S1         S20         O7                      
##                   0.0000000  -0.4405556  -0.2066667 -0.0900000                      
## Block:                    1           2           3          4          5          6
##                   0.0000000  -0.1808333  -0.0875000 -0.2066667 -0.5016667 -0.6875000
```

The dummy coefficients with one level, in this case the Intercept, are not factors so extract the ones with more than one level and get the maximum coef from each factor producing a data frame as shown.

```
max.lev <- function(x) data.frame(level = names(x)[which.max(x)], value = max(x))
do.call("rbind", lapply(dc[lengths(dc) > 1], max.lev))
##         level      value
## Variety Ladak 0.09458333
## Date     None 0.00000000
## Block       1 0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothenieck. That works but I need to be able to store the individual dummy value but my code doesn't seem to work that way in R Studio. See below when I apply your code the results. You can see its not giving me Screen.7, etc      see revised code up top.

Comment: Have modified last line and added additional code to produce a data frame with factor name, maximum level and values.

Answer (score 0):

You should take that `pref = c( )` out of your loop, otherwise, your loop will keep resetting it every time and you will always store only the value related to your last `i`.